# How to get the url to tag & category base set by the user?

Tags: categories, theme-development, permalinks, tags

I'm searching for half an hour now on how to get the url/permalink base in Wordpress (the 'category' and 'tag' value set in the backend). Could you please point me in the right direction?

I want to dynamically print the following - but only replace the `tags` and `category` part (not the tag/category itself):

```
<a href="/tags/my-tag">My Tag</a>
<a href="/category/my-category">My Category</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You really shouldn't need this, as you should be outputting the URLs via the API: [`get_tag_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag_link), [`get_category_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link), [`get_term_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link).

However, for the sake of answering the question, they're stored in options:

```
get_option( 'tag_base' );
get_option( 'category_base' );
```

Comment: The reason is that the name or slug of the tag will be the same in dev/testing and production - but the `tag_id` will vary! So my thought was, that it is more efficient to just grab the set `tag_base` and append the slug - other than query the database via `get_term_link` to get the full url. And with the second option, the slug has to be hard-coded, too.