# Get category base permalink

Tags: categories, permalinks

i need to place category base permalink in my theme like this

```
<?php if ( is_category('in-theaters') ) { ?>
<li class="active"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/genre/in-theaters/"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i><span><?php echo intheaters; ?></span></a></li>
<?php } else { ?>

<li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/genre/in-theaters/"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i><span><?php echo intheaters; ?></span></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

so i need this output result

http://mywebsite/category/

Comment: And what do you expect to happen on that category page?

Comment: I just need to display the category base permalink on my sidebar

Comment: Do you mean category _term_?

Comment: just category base permalink like "category"

Comment: WP gives you no such page out of the box. You'd have to build it, so only you would know the path to it.

Comment: I know the route well, I need it for those who don't know it, I need to view the link in the sidebar https://prnt.sc/txa5wf

Comment: Why do you need to display the category base permalink in the sidebar? If you're trying to display URLs for categories then there are better ways to do that and dedicated functions for it. Please edit your question to include context

Comment: question updated

Comment: You're asking for a category base but it looks like what you using in your code is the URL to the category? If so, have you looked at get_term_link()?

Comment: yes i've looked for  get_term_link() but i don't need category term! i just need category base url like http://mywebsite/category/  i need to print with php

Comment: You could always deduct the slug from the link URL using str_replace() but there appears to be a better answer (not tested) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91662/how-to-get-the-url-to-tag-category-base-set-by-the-user

Comment: don't work <?php echo get_option( 'category_base' ); ?>/genre/in-theaters/